# UISearchBar delegate method calls only one time in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

In iOS 7 searchbar delegate method `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`is not being called on second time. When i tap first time on searchbar then it is calling `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` this method but when i tap second time then it is not calling its delegate method while it is working good in iOS 6. problem is only with iOS 7

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS7 used `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` and my problem is fixed but still i don't know why it is not calling `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` in iOS 7 every time. this is called only once but `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` is called every time

Comment: Just a heads up - searchBarTextDidBeginEditing is called only once, while the last active textview/textfield was search view. If you have some other textfield/textview in your view structure, then by selecting that one, and then again search field - it will call this delegate again. But yes,  easier is just to switch searchBarTextDidBeginEditing to searchBarShouldBeginEditing.